# Find text and show value if condition is met

Tags: vba, excel

Can someone help me a little bit. Picture is attached.
What I need is a code that will find "TOTAL PURCHASE" that has offset(-9)="USD" and then in cell D1 show the value of 100.

This is what I have

```
Sub vbavjezba()
    Dim total As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Object
    Dim usd As Range

    Set rng = Application.Range("A1:A21")
    Set total = Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A21").Find(what:="TOTAL PURCHASE")
    Set usd = Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A21").Find(what:="USD")`

    For Each cell In rng
        If total.Offset(-9) = usd Then
            Worksheet(1).Range.("D1").value=total.offset(,2)
        Else
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Dude, this is not a code for free site. Here we help you to solve problems with your code, not to develop a code for your needs. Please read> [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: This is clearly off-topic due to: Questions seeking debugging help ("*why isn't this code working?*") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got an answer that will find the first instance of USD and check if TOTAL PURCHASE is 9 rows below it, if found then copy the adjacent cell to D1, if not found then search for the next USD and repeat the checks:

```
Option Explicit

Sub vbavjezba()
Dim total As Variant
Dim usd As Variant
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A21")
Set usd = Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A21").Find(what:="USD") 'Find the first instance of USD

repeatcheck:
If usd.Offset(9, 0).Value = "TOTAL PURCHASE" Then
    Worksheets(1).Range("D1").Value = usd.Offset(9, 1).Value
Else
    Set usd = rng.FindNext(After:=usd) 'Find the next instance of USD
    If Not usd Is Nothing Then 'IF found
        GoTo repeatcheck 'go back to repeatcheck to see if TOTAL PURCHASE is 9 rows below it
    Else
        MsgBox "Not Found!"
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Thank you. Have you tried it? because it does not work for me..I keep getting object defined error. and debuger highlights everything in "If" statement.

Comment: Hi, yeah I have tried and tested it and it works for me, I was going to update my answer to include being able to find the next Total Purchase, but I'm guessing you might not have defined your variables properly...

Comment: Well ofcourse...since it is looking only first instance of "USD"...I need it to loop through the whole range and give me the adjacent cell of "total purchase" only if it has "usd" on its offset(-9)

Comment: "FoundAt" variable is not defined and debuger again stops at the "If" statement.

Comment: Do you have an Option Explicit at the top of your module? if you comment this line out, does it work?

Comment: I bypassed option excplicit again it stoped at "If" statement

Comment: If it is possible, could you maybe upload your spreadsheet to something like Google Drive and add the link to the comments, so I can have a look at it? As I mentioned, I have tried and tested it and it does work for me, so I'm guessing you have something else at play here...

Comment: (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cQKKOVn_2bcer90VNhYzqMW0EIzuhaZm)  The ranges are a bit different  but this is an example anway.

Comment: The issue is that you have multiple USD and TOTAL PURCHASE cells, if this wasn't the case as you didn't mentioned this in your original question, then the answer I provided would work... Let me see if I can re-write my answer to do what you want it to do....

Comment: Yes.I  thought it was clear on the picture...apologies..In the original report that I cant publish in one column I have enormus amount of repetition of "TOTAL PURCHASE" and "USD" but...there is only one instance of total purchase that has offset on -9 that is usd...i cant figure out any other way to extract the data of adjacent cell of TOTAL PURCHASE since there are over 100 repetitions of that word...its hard since you cant see the original report..

Comment: @FlipFlop17, updated my answer, please check it should now work for you, also please could you mark my response as an answer? Thank you.